# Implement Captcha on Embedded System

Tags: embedded, captcha

I have an Embedded system with WebServer running. I need to provide captcha mechanism for Webpage served by the WebServer. **How can I implement Captcha in the Embedded System (Device)?**

I have seen google reCAPTCHA but it required website registration to generate keys which is not possible for embedded device.

Comment: You are wrong. First of all, there's no difference if you are running your web server on a PC, embedded device, or VPS, or whatever (in general, skipping corner cases). Secondly, generating API keys has absolutely nothing to do of what hardware or software you are using to host your web pages.

Comment: Ok. So if I am running on embedded devices (with the DHCP Client) in my network then what should give in "Domains" and "Label" while registering on Google Captcha using URL "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create"

Comment: That's a different question, that falls out of scope on this site. You need to expose your web-server to outside world - setup static ip, port forwarding on your router to your device, configure CNAME record if required, etc. There's plenty of information out there on how to setup fully functional web server at your home.

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on your embedded device, but generally goes like so:

If you can't guarantee that your embedded webserver will have connectivity to the Internet (which you can't, normally, as it is up to the end user in what environment your device operates - It might be an isolated, private network) - You simply **cannot** use public Captacha services, but rather have to implement a local, freestanding captcha mechanism.

If you *can* assure you have connectivity to the public network, your web server should know the domain it is serving (has to be configured into your device somehow anyways) and you should only embed the Captcha after that domain name is known (by an automated or assisted manual registration mechanism)